# NameError:Admin not found in django

Tags: django

The urls.py of the project is this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Sdr.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^Sdr/', include('Sdr.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('Sdr.sdr.urls')),
)
```

The urls.py of the app looks like this

```
# Import django modules
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
# Import custom modules
import settings


admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('Sdr.sdr.urls')),
)
```

The error I am getting is exception found is

```
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'admin' is not defined
```

Comment: Like ignacio said you have to uncomment the admin import and autodiscover

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You forgot to import `admin` in the project's urls.py. Read harder.

Answer (score 9):

Uncomment the following in your project's urls.py.

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
```

Answer (score 8):

Faced with the same problem in tutorial.
Try to add in `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
```